# Lead History to converted opportunity

Tags: opportunity, lead-conversion, history-tracking, opportunity-history

Is there any native way or package that carries over the Lead History tracking to the Opportunity when Lead is converted?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this could work

1. The `OpportunityHistory.CreatedBy` and `CreatedDate` fields are populated by the system, not via Apex
2. Apex can't write to these objects anyway

A better solution would be to create either a Text Area (long) field on Opportunity where you use Apex to populate the lead's field history (truncated to fit field size)

or

Create a custom master-detail object under Opportunity called `LeadConversion_History__c` and populate accordingly.

Comment: I understand that I can simulate it with a custom object and apex but I'm looking more for a native or quicker solution to this.  We are trying to avoid a longer custom solution if possible.

Comment: @dphil - There is no native solution I know of; managed packages would have same limitation as Apex limitations above

Comment: The thing with managed packages is that we wouldn't have to do the underlying work for it.  Thanks for trying though!